# How to delete a sonarqube project from mysqldb?

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-4.5

I know i can delete **Sonarqube** project from sonarqube web UI with admin credentials. ***I want to know whether can we delete project by logging into MySQL DB?***

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

It is not recommended at all to touch database. Only UI and web services must be used to prevent from having corrupted data.

Comment: Thanks Simon..I just want to know if i run analysis on a project, how it stores in DB? i mean how it stores like tables or modules or anything else

Comment: We want database to be a black box. It evolves frequently among versions.